# Display output from a table using python regex

Tags: python

I am quite new to python. I had to fetch a table from telnetting a "Device Under Test" and obtain it in a logfile using python which i did successfully using below program

```
import os
import sys
import getpass
import re
import telnetlib

HOST = "ip of host"
user = raw_input("Enter your remote account: ")
password = raw_input("Enter the password: ")

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
tn.read_until("Password: ")
tn.write(password + "\n")
tn.read_until("*>")
tn.write("command-to-be-executed\n")
tn.write("exit\n")
output = tn.read_all()
f= open("C:/Python27/Scripts/logfile/module_show.txt" , "w+")
f.write(output)
f.close()
tn.close()
```

Now I have to read the logfile fetched and  print the below specific line as per first and last column:

|ER  |2    |252       |wPWs_sTE1-3-2                  |               |3.3.3.3        |30002  |30002  |sUMoF |

|ER  |1    |10251     |wPWd_sTE1-3-1                  |               |3.3.3.3        |100000 |32768  |dUMoF |

i wrote a separate program for this but this is not working . please see the program below :

```
import re

regex = re.compile("^(\|ER)")
with open("C:/Python27/Scripts/logfile/module_show.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        result = regex.search(line)
        if result:
            print line

f.close()
```

Kindly help me out on the same  ?

Comment: What is the structure of the data written to "module_show.txt" and what is the expected output format?

Comment: the data is written as shown above , i will write this once again                |ER |2 |252 |wPWs_sTE1-3-2 | |3.3.3.3 |30002 |30002 |sUMoF |
|ER |1 |10251 |wPWd_sTE1-3-1 | |3.3.3.3 |100000 |32768 |dUMoF |                and i want to display or print  this line in same format

Comment: thanks shanmuga  but i figured it out                                                import re

regex = re.compile("(F\s\|\r)$")
with open("C:/Python27/Scripts/logfile/module_show.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        result = regex.search(line)
        if result:
            print line
f.close()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all,

I figured this out after a little bit more of thinking , i did not took carriage return into thinking before implementing regexp:

```
import os
import sys
import getpass
import re
import telnetlib

HOST = "ip address"
user = raw_input("Enter your remote account: ")
password = raw_input("Enter the password: ")

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
tn.read_until("Password: ")
tn.write(password + "\n")
tn.read_until("*>")
tn.write("command to be executed\n")
tn.write("exit\n")
output = tn.read_all()
f= open("C:/Python27/Scripts/logfile/module_show.txt" , "w+")
f.write(output)
f.close()
tn.close()
regex = re.compile("(F\s\|\r)$")
with open("C:/Python27/Scripts/logfile/module_show.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        result = regex.search(line)
        if result:
            print line
f.close()
```